# Team Foundation Server 12 API with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, tfs

So we've run into another issue, and are hoping the combined knowledge of SO can congregate and come up with some sort of a solution.

We're running a program that has a 'Tasks' system. A person in the company, using the software, might have a request, or a bug fix they wish to create a new task of. So they do it through our current task system. Now that we've implemented source control into our dev team, we have the fantastic functionality that TFS provides - Branching, Merging, Conflict resolution, and of course - the Agile side of things - sprints, scrums, etc.

Now we are trying to move our tasks system to a new level - people reporting these bugs/add ons will create a task, but this will in turn move that into our workflow on the TFS.

So we've nearly got it working. The program however is based on the .NET 4.0 Client Profile Framework, and we hit this issue:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3274: The     primary reference "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3275: The primary reference "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".
```

Now I have a somewhat limited knowledge of how to manipulate something that was built in .NET4.5 to work with .NET4.0, but as far as my knowledge extends - I can set the build framework to be .NET4.5 and it runs smoothly.

However, my question is - is there a way to get this working with .NET4.0? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just upgrade to .NET 4.5?

Comment: At the moment the lead dev is unavailable to congregate on the matter and we've been asked by the supervisor to see if we can implement it on it's current framework.

Comment: This begs the question: What's creating these tasks programmatically? If it's based on user input, can't the users just use the TFS web client and add the tasks there?

Comment: I wonder which framework version was used by the "TFS 11" SDK? I'm sure that most of the API calls you need to use against your "TFS 12" server you could make using the "TFS 11" (2012) API.

Comment: Thats a great idea! I'll try run it by today and see how it goes. Cheers!

Comment: @DanielMann We are the ones that will be working the scope into a more narrowed concept with the creator of the task. However, the tasks are able to be submitted to the current system by over 150 personnel, and before pushing them into the TFS, we need to make sure that the content isn't a) a duplicate entry, and b) has a well-defined scope on which we can create a well timed est. completion date. The users are solely going to create tasks into the current system - the developers will be forwarding this on to the TFS. (FYI, the task system is for multiple dept's, not just ours).