# The type or namespace name 'TeamFoundation' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I added the following reference to my ASP.NET MVC 4 application using .net 4.0.

I also included the namespace in my Application , but still I see the following error :

```
 Reference : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

   "The type or namespace name 'TeamFoundation' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' "
```

I have another console application and I didnt see this error while using the reference in that application . Is there something different I need to do for a Web/MVC application ?
   Please let me know .

There is also this warning I see :

```
Warning 1   The primary reference "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
```

Comment: Amir Popovich is right. But I don't get it, why the hell do you need a reference to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll ? It has nothing to do with MVC4 !

Comment: haha.. I am using TFS API and developing a web application . I need that assembly for this purpose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are trying to reference a **higher version** dll(`.net 4.5`) in a **lower version project** (`.net 4.0`).

Either **upgrade** your project to `.net 4.5` or reference the `.net 4.0` version dll.

Comment: Yes that's logical. We can not use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client" version:12.0.0.0 , runtime version :v4.0.xxxx  with .Net 4.0. See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050770/team-foundation-server-12-api-with-net-4-0). The problem is that the run time version doesn't clearly indicate that.